# missing right parenthesis insert statement ORA-00907

Tags: oracle

```
INSERT INTO packageamounts 
   SELECT 
       '6abc148c-20b7-cd34-c433-5472b1b9627d', packageamounts.name, '', '', 1, 1, 
       NULL, 0, NULL, packageamounts.package_id, '', packageamounts.amount, 
       packageamounts.taxtype_id, packageamounts.unit_value, 'd754c9c9-a0cb-ad43-b237-546c7f6eb903' 
   FROM 
       packageamounts 
   WHERE 
       packageamounts.id IN (SELECT id 
                             FROM (SELECT * 
                                   FROM packageamounts 
                                   WHERE packageamounts.insprovider_id = 'b7f4525a-0ddd-292a-a574-4d1c742e7ff8' 
                                   ORDER BY effective_date DESC ) AS v 
                             WHERE v.effective_date <= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                               AND v.deleted = 0  
                             ORDER BY v.effective_date DESC, v.date_entered DESC )  v 
   WHERE  v.deleted = 0 ORDER BY v.effective_date DESC, v.date_entered DESC);
```

Comment: The structure of INSERT is: `INSERT INTO [TABLE] ([list of column names]) VALUES([list of values])`. The INSERT described above doesn't look anything like that.

Comment: The problem is in Where condition. Insert runs fine if we remove Where condition. I have tried all the subqueries are running without any error

Comment: You *can* insert with `INSERT INTO [TABLE] [list of values]` but it's not recommended because you have to provide *all* the fields in the table, in the correct order, and if the table-structure changes - it'll break your code. If you can run the `SELECT` part and retrieve the required results you should be good - just remove the ordering from your query as @Multisync suggested below

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO packageamounts 
   SELECT 
       '6abc148c-20b7-cd34-c433-5472b1b9627d', name, '', '', 1, 1, 
       NULL, 0, NULL, package_id, '', amount, 
       taxtype_id, unit_value, 'd754c9c9-a0cb-ad43-b237-546c7f6eb903' 
   FROM 
       packageamounts 
   WHERE 
       packageamounts.id IN (SELECT id 
                             FROM (SELECT * 
                                   FROM packageamounts 
                                   WHERE packageamounts.insprovider_id = 'b7f4525a-0ddd-292a-a574-4d1c742e7ff8' 
                                  ) AS v 
                             WHERE v.effective_date <= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
                               AND v.deleted = 0) 
   and deleted = 0 
   ORDER BY effective_date DESC, date_entered DESC;
```

(removed some extra ORDER BY + there was an extra bracket at the end)

Another query which does the same:

```
INSERT INTO packageamounts 
   SELECT 
       '6abc148c-20b7-cd34-c433-5472b1b9627d', name, '', '', 1, 1, 
       NULL, 0, NULL, package_id, '', amount, 
       taxtype_id, unit_value, 'd754c9c9-a0cb-ad43-b237-546c7f6eb903' 
   FROM 
       packageamounts 
   WHERE insprovider_id = 'b7f4525a-0ddd-292a-a574-4d1c742e7ff8' 
     and effective_date <= TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
     and deleted = 0
   ORDER BY effective_date DESC, date_entered DESC;
```

Comment: Its not working.Brackets are correct,there is a close bracket for every start bracket.Moreover, i cannot remove order by from the query,its required

Comment: @Anjali Sachdev The last bracket in your query is not correct - try to find the correlated left. ORDER BY doesn't play any role in your query

Comment: @Anjali Sachdev Moreover, you don't even need IN + subquery